# 'AnyObject' is not convertible to ABRecordRef

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I’m trying to get peoples birthdays from the address book with swift.

```
    let ab = ABAddressBook.sharedAddressBook()
    var birthday: CFDateRef?       
    for person in ab.people() {
        birthday = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABBirthdayProperty)
    ...
```

But I get the following error in xcode:

> AnyObject' is not convertible to ABRecordRef

`ABRecordCopyValue` expects an `ABRecordRef` Object as the first argument but person is of type `AnyObject`.
It also doesn’t work with `person as ABRecordRef`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ABRecordRef` is the same as `ABRecord` in Swift. You should be able to use the simpler APIs from the `ABRecord` class:

```
for person in ab.people() as [ABPerson] {
    person.valueForProperty(kABBirthdayProperty)...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that advice. That means in Swift we don’t use `Copy` functions and `Ref` properties?

Comment: You certainly can — especially in those APIs which don't have plain class equivalents. But here it's easier not to.